# List object cannot be coerced to type 'double

Tags: r

I use R and when I try to run the following code:

```
f = scan(file="c:\\myfile.txt", sep=' ', what=list('numeric'))

MY_MATRIX.M = matrix(f, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

Var.names = c('column1','column2', 'column3', 'column4')
colnames(MY_MATRIX.M) = Var.names

TEST = data.frame(MY_MATRIX.M)

t1 = TEST[which(TEST[,4] == 0, arr.ind = TRUE),]
t2 = TEST[which(TEST[,4] == 1, arr.ind = TRUE),]
```

I have the following error:

```
Error in which(TEST[,4] == 0, arr.ind = TRUE : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

My file has 4 columns and consist of numbers like an array.
Can anyone give me a hand on solving the problem ?

Comment: reproducible example please?  http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Comment: Try `class(TEST[,4])` and `typeof(TEST[,4])` and `head(TEST[,4])` and let us know what it says?

Comment: > class(TEST[,4])
[1] "list"
> typeof(TEST[,4]) 
[1] "list"
> head(TEST[,4])
$column3
  [1] "column1" "column2"   "column3"  "1"         "1247"      "105"      
  [7] "0"         "2"         "1668"  ... ... ...

Comment: what the result of ```str(TEST)```?

Comment: > str(TEST)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ index    :List of 1
  ..$ index: chr  "mor" "cal" "der" "1" ...
 $ mor:List of 1
  ..$ mor: chr  "mor" "cal" "der" "1" ...
 $ cal  :List of 1
  ..$ cal: chr  "mor" "cal" "der" "1" ...
 $ der :List of 1
  ..$ der: chr  "mor" "cal" "der" "1" ...

Comment: I suspect that your `scan()` call is messed up.  What happens if you do `TEST <- read.table("c:\\myfile.txt")` ?

Comment: you need just to remove the what args from the scan. f <- scan(file="c:\\myfile.txt", sep=' ')

Comment: voted to close as too localized.

Answer (score 8):

The problem you're experiencing is due to the argument `what=list(numeric)`. You want to tell `R` that the file has just `numeric` values, *not* that it contains lists with numeric elements. So just use `what=numeric`, or don't use `what` at all.

I don't import text files often, but when I do, I prefer `read`.

Comment: do you mean `read.table()` ?

Comment: The `read` family - all the data I use is in `csv` format so I guess I've always just used `read.csv`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Finally you are right.. the problem was in what=list(numeric).